# Fastest way to read 100's of files accessing them only once?

Tags: c

In my case I path to a folder and my code is to read all the files in the directory and subdirectory.

I need to read ALL the files, I only need to read it once (I don't need to cache anything) and I don't need the file contents after I process it.

I was thinking of opening all the files (100+ of them) at once with `open` followed with a `posix_fadvise(f, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED);` then use threads to read each file one at a time (6 cores * 2 threads per core = 12threads/files I'll be reading at a time). Is this the fastest way to do it? Would there be problems if I call posix_fadvise on too many files? Should I `read` each file or use `mmap`? I'm not sure how I should go about this or limitations

Comment: Note that opening many files simultaneously does not scale well. Many operating systems have a relatively small limit for open files per process. It should be accessible via stdio.h macro `FOPEN_MAX` and it may be as low as 8. On POSIX systems you might be able to find the limit with `getconf OPEN_MAX`.

Comment: That's pretty low. On my system its 16 but `getconf OPEN_MAX` is 1024